# Can't get class as attribute which has one-to-one relationship?

Tags: python, django, one-to-one, twython

I'm new to Python/Django so forgive me if I overlooked some easy mistakes.
I'm trying to use Twython and pretty much copying the code [here](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython-django/blob/master/twython_django_oauth/views.py)

I can't seem to get the TwitterProfile with the dot syntax like this:

```
user = request.user.twitterprofile
```

It gives me the error:

```
DoesNotExist at /social/user_timeline/
TwitterProfile matching query does not exist.
```

But if I get the profile like this:

```
user = TwitterProfile.objects.get(user = u)
```

It seems to work fine... Spent several hours just figuring that out..

I also had to add a related_name for user in the TwitterProfile class:

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='twitteruser')
```

Any idea why I can't access the TwitterProfile like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`related_name` defines the name of the attribute on the linked model, so you can do:

```
user = request.user.twitteruser
```

Comment: You're the first to know what it means!

Answer (score 3):

First off you're going to need to define your `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` in settings.py:

```
from twython_django_oauth.models import TwitterProfile

AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = TwitterProfile
```

Then, you can access your profile from request:

```
request.user.get_profile()
```

Comment: drewman, thanks I used this before as UserProfile, but I want a Facebook profile as well so dokkaebi's answer seems more suitable :)